# Rspec spec for put action not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, put

Can anyone see why my put spec for my controller wont pass?

Here is what my update action in my controller looks like:

```
def update
 @user = User.find(current_user.id)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @user.update_attributes(permitted_update_params)
     format.html { redirect_to new_topup_path, notice: 'Billing address was succesfully updated' }
     format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
   else
     format.html { render action: "edit" }
     format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

And my spec looks like this:

```
context "given a user who wants to update their billing address" do
 let!(:user) { create(:user, billing_address: "My initial address") }

 before(:each) do
   allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) {:user}
   patch :update, { user: { :billing_address => "My Second address" } }
 end

 it "should update the users billing address" do
   expect(user.billing_address).to eq("My Second address")
 end
end
```

My spec displays this message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(user.billing_address).to eq("My Second address")

   expected: "My Second address"
        got: "My initial address"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to reload the `user` instance in your test. The database has been updated, but the `user` instance won't update itself to reflect that.

```
expect(user.reload.billing_address).to eq("My Second address")
```

There are also other problems with your code, like this line:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) {:user}
```

You've defined a user with `let(:user)`, which means you now have a `user` variable available to your spec - note `user`, not `:user`!

Comment: I just tried that, but it still isnt persisting the new data :(

Comment: `def permitted_update_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :billing_address)
   end`

Comment: Also, this line is wrong - `allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) {:user}` - you're returning the symbol `:user` instead of the instance `user` you're defining.

Comment: Yeah i corrected that, still not passing (Btw i really appreciate this assistance)

Answer (score 0):

You should reload your user before expectation:

```
before(:each) do
   allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) {:user}
   patch :update, { user: { :billing_address => "My Second address" } }
   user.reload
end
```

Comment: I just tried that, but it still isn't persisting the new data :(

Comment: @NdaJunior, did you check your controller returns success response?

Answer (score 0):

A controller spec should test the behavior *of the action*. Your action's behavior can be roughly described as:

- Get the permitted parameters
- Update the user
- If the update succeeded, redirect
- Otherwise redisplay the edit page

Updating the user is the responsibility of the model, not the controller. If you are concerned that a particular set of parameters will (or won't) update the user instance, create a model spec and test the parameters there.